# Multi-class classification as a hypothesis testing problem

Tags: classification, statistics, multilabel-classification

I'm diving into the logistic distribution and its applications in classification problem (see [my old question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/normal-distribution-instead-of-logistic-distribution-for-classification/48087#48087) for more details about my idea).

As discussed in my old post, logistic regression, in fact, can be seen as a hypothesis testing problem.

My question is that: is there any hypothesis-testing-based classifier for multi-class classification problems ?